# Issue with Serbian Characters in PDF generated with jsPdf in React Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am utilizing jsPdf to convert HTML to PDF in a React web application. I've added a custom font (PTSans) to the PDF using the following code:

```
pdf.addFont("/assets/fonts/PTSans.ttf", "PTSans", "normal");
pdf.setFont("PTSans");
pdf.html(document.getElementById("userinputform"), {
    callback: function () {
        // Some logic
    }
});
```

However, when my HTML includes Serbian characters, they do not appear correctly in the PDF. I've experimented with a simple text snippet, and it displays properly:

```
pdf.text(
    "hello in English and Serbian is рaвo нa шкoлoвaњe. Шкoлoвaњe трeбa дa буде бeспл",
    100,
    100
);
```

Could someone provide insights or suggestions on how to ensure proper rendering of Serbian characters when converting HTML to PDF using jsPdf in a React application?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.